# Как распарсить?

Tags: java, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется (находится внутри String abc):

```
[[["Почему кошка собаку?","Why cat is dog?","Pochemu koshka sobaku?",""]],,"en",,[["Почему",[4],1,0,1000,0,1,0],["кошка",[5],1,0,869,1,2,0],["собаку?",[6],1,0,505,2,4,0]],[["Why",4,[["Почему",1000,1,0],["Зачем",0,1,0],["Почему бы",0,1,0],["Чего",0,1,0]],[[0,3]],"Why cat is dog?"],["cat is",5,[["кошка",869,1,0],["кошки",130,1,0],["кошкам",0,1,0],["кошке",0,1,0],["кошками",0,1,0]],[[4,10]],""],["dog ?",6,[["собаку?",505,1,0]],[[11,15]],""]],,,[["en"]],64]
```

Требуется: достать первую часть текста (в данном случае - *Почему кошка собаку?*)

Вопрос: как?

Comment: Обязательно на Java? Я б ту задачу на перле набросал быстренько :)

Comment: @klopp Давайте на перле. У меня уже был опыт перевода кода на перле в джаву. Только просьба не использовать чего-то перлоспецифического, чего нету в джаве (библиотеки там разные и др.)

Comment: Cам XML покажите. У меня рука на XML::XPath набита, в java xpath есть? Если нет - думаю, разбор трудностей не вызовет?

Comment: Это не xml. Я вам показал оригинал - другого нет.

Xpath в наличии.

Comment: А, в смысле нужно только распарсить ответ? Тогда пас, в перле это решается элементарно :)

    my @data = eval($response);

В `@data` получаем обычный многомерный массив в соответствии со скобочкам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abc.delete(0, 3);

abc.delete(texto.indexOf("\""), -1);
```

Comment: Вон оно как...

     'java.lang.String' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: @alexlz забыл сказать, надо предварительно переделать String в StringBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь распарсить формат JSON. Для этого нужно воспользоваться, понятно, JSON-парсером.

Посмотрите сюда: [json.org/java](http://json.org/java/).

Вы можете, конечно, попытаться не использовать парсер, надеясь, что структура строки никогда не поменяется. (Например, что между квадратными скобками никогда-никогда не появятся пробелы.) Для такого случая вы можете сделать и по-другому, но "нечестное" решение будет более хрупким, плохим в поддержке и расширении, и подверженным разного рода ошибкам.

Comment: Json это вроде { }, нет?

Comment: @danpetruk: не только. смотрите http://www.json.org/ насчёт массивов.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = abc.split("\"");
String result = tokens[1];
```